# Terraform error Invalid count argument after upgrade from TF 0.11 to 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

After upgrade from 0.11 to 0.12 something that worked before starting failing due to dependencies:

```
Error: Invalid count argument
  on ../modules/app-web/fargate.tf line 289, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "proxy2target_group_1":
 289:   count                    = var.allow_security_group_id == "" ? 0 : 1
The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the count depends on.
```

which indeed depends on another resource: `allow_security_group_id = module.repl-ssm-tunnel-proxy.this_security_group_id`
But is really the only solution to find all such resources and run TF multiple times with -target ? Why did it work before? Can I get it working without multiple TF runs?

Update: I have tried the suggested solution, running `terraform apply -target=aws_codepipeline.codepipeline_prod -target=aws_codepipeline.codepipeline_stage_from_github -target=aws_codepipeline.codepipeline_stage_from_ecr -target=module.repl-ssm-tunnel-proxy -target=module.direct-connect.aws_route_tables.private` which did not fail but also has not applied anything. Perhaps because all these are inside modules (i.e. production.tf -> modules/myapp -> modules/helper-XY) and since I did not target the top-level module (myapp) nothing was applied?
And of course if I try to add the top-level module, it fails again because of the original count problem: `terraform apply ... -target=module.direct-connect.aws_route_tables.private -target module.direct_connect` Catch 22? :-(

Comment: Can you edit your question so that it includes a [mcve] that results in this error please?

Comment: This constraint also existed in Terraform 0.11, but it had a different error message that was less detailed and didn't include the suggestion to use `-target`. If you didn't see it on Terraform 0.11 then I would guess that your Terraform 0.11 configuration evolved gradually over time and by the time you added the `count` to this resource the dependency was already created and so the ID value was already known. The error would appear only if the plan included a "create" action for the other resource, which is why the `-target` option works to get around it.

Comment: It's tough to get into specifics with the limited information you shared here but the general idea would be to determine which resources are in the dependency subgraph for `output "this_security_group_id` in your module and `-target` them all together. I can't say whether the ones you listed in your question are the right ones because I'm not familiar with the dependency relationships in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 0.12 to 0.13 removed a number of these warnings and the remaining one was easy to fix by changing the code.